# Getting Access token validity

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, jwt, passport.js

I am using passport to authenticate user into my application

I have created a passport strategy for the same

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL:  process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL,
    userProfileURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo',
    accessType: 'offline'
  }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
       console.log(refreshToken)
        let profileSort = extractProfile(profile)
         mongooeHelperFunction.findUserByEmail(profileSort.email).then(response => {
           if (!response) {
            mongooeHelperFunction.createNewUser(profileSort)
            .then(res => { 
               let newRes = {...res}
                newRes["accessToken"] = accessToken
                cb(null, newRes)
            })
            .catch(error => {  throw error  })
           } else {
                let newRes = {...response}
                newRes["accessToken"] = accessToken
                cb(null, newRes)
           }
        })
        .catch(error => {  throw error  })
    }
))
```

(the above is very similar to passport strategy we usually create)

To get refresh token above, I am doing this in my api route

```
router.get("/google",  passport.authenticate('google', {accessType: 'offline', prompt: 'consent', scope: ['profile', 'email',  'https://mail.google.com/' ] }));
```

**Question:** This does give me an access token. How can I know when the access token will expire?

My initial goal is to get a new access token via refresh token whenever the access token is expired.

Can anyone help me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

To add to the above answer, oauth2 jwt tokens are encoded not encrypted, hence you can easily read the expiry time by decoding the token.
There are 2 common ways to verify if the token is expired, using standard jwt libraries. I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

Assuming you have the public key or secret, use the verify method to check if token is expired. This throws an error if you are using an expired token.

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var token ='eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJmb28iOiJiYXIiLCJpYXQiOjE1NDYzOTYxMDYsImV4cCI6MTU0NjM5NjEwN30.qFeaKny2Ruk7ZeZsHGpPcw6aksyZHUfDOmb6EvgiGIo';
var verified = jwt.verify(token, 'secret');
```

Decode the token using the decode method. You can get the expiry time from the exp field in the decoded object

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var token ='eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJmb28iOiJiYXIiLCJpYXQiOjE1NDYzOTYxMDYsImV4cCI6MTU0NjM5NjEwN30.qFeaKny2Ruk7ZeZsHGpPcw6aksyZHUfDOmb6EvgiGIo';
var decoded = jwt.decode(token);
console.log('Expiry timestamp----------->', decoded.exp);
```

Also for testing this make sure you set the expiry time while creating the JWT

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, 'secret', {expiresIn: '1h'});
```

You can read more about JWTs here https://jwt.io/introduction/

Answer (score 1):

OAuth tokens contain all the information in them in an encrypted format. They are a form of JWT tokens and you can easily decrypt your token [here](https://jwt.io/).

For programmatic purposes, you can parse the JWT using npm pakcages. One of the best implementations is by [Auth0](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken)  and that should help you avoid writing manual decryption algorithms.